# Managing multiple independent domains from one management VM without RDP

Tags: active-directory

I'm looking for the best way, how to manage multiple independent AD domains from one Virtual Machine...

Imagine one central point, where you have an access to the different networks with different AD domains. I need to find a way, how to comfortably manage user and computer AD accounts in each domain from one VM without using RDP to access DC in each domain. Problem is, that there is no trust set betweet those domains so administrator has to use different sets of credentials. What could be the most comfortable and secure way how to do this? Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by creating multiple shortcuts with targets like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /netonly /user:user@domain.local "mmc %SystemRoot%\system32\dsa.msc /domain=domain.local"
```